# Custom Subview on a iOS view has null outlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xib, subview

I have a view called FeedView, handled by FeedViewController.

I also have a XIB called "NearestStore" which is handled by a view controller named "NearestStoreViewController". NearestStore xib has labels, buttons, etc. In the view controller I have outlets that are connected to the subviews in NearestStore.xib.

NearestStore inherits from UIButton (so it's easier to handle click event).

On FeedViewController.xib I have a UIButton that has been set to be of type NearestStore.

So far so good. This is on my FeedViewController:

```
__weak IBOutlet NearestStoreButton *btn_nearestStore;
```

The outlet is connected on the xib to the outlet.

NearestStoreViewController has several outlets to subviews like:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet  UILabel *lbl_distance; 
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet  UIImageView *img_distance;
```

For some reason, on my FeedViewController the reference to btn_nearestStore is fine, but all the subviews are nil.

For example:

```
btn_nearestStore.lbl_distance
```

is nil

What am I missing?

Comment: I find this really difficult to follow. What do the 2 view controllers have in common? Just describe the details that matter. How are you combining the XIBs?

Comment: FeedViewController is the parent view. Inside it I have a smaller view that I want to encapsulate on another view (and view controller), so I can reuse on another view. The inner smaller view is NearestStoreButton

Comment: how are you creating your NearestStoreButton instance? just specifying a custom class instead of UIButton, doesn't mean it will be loaded from the NearestStore nib; you should create a wrapper for loading an instance from external nib file or load nib file using code

Comment: post your xib file or store boadrd with referece connected view. and code for initializing the view from xib.

Comment: Why are the subviews (nonatomic, weak) - when/ who creates lbl_distance and img_distance

Comment: I left an answer for why this is not working. There is no proper way (that i know of) of dealing with this if you really need the multiple xibs. Let me know (edit your question) if you also want a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds exactly as the system is supposed to work. It is not easy to create a custom widget using xibs.

#### Here's how it works:

Your FeedViewController will preform xib loading for the corresponding FeedView.
During this load, it notices the NearestStoreButton subview. As a consequence, it creates such a view using the `- (id)initWithCoder:` message on the NearestStoreButton class. It will not magically notice the corresponding .xib nor the corresponding viewController.

If you need to use a xib within a xib, you need to do the loading manually for all subviews. Keep in mind that you somehow need to create/use the appropriate owners (view controllers) for these secondary xibs.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your description, but this sounds like a problem with "owner" of the  loaded NearestStoreButton XIB. When you load a NIB, you give the loader an owner, and its this owner on which most outlet bindings and actions are made. If you're loading your `NearestStoreButton` with `UINib`, then when you call `instantiateWithOwner:options:`, make sure you pass the object on which the outlets should be set as the owner.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling the outlet? If you are trying to access the property in the `initWithCoder` method of the view, it's not guaranteed that object has been instantiated.

If you access your property in the `awakeFromNib` method within the view you should be able to get it. For instance, I have a custom view, and my code looks as such:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        //Don't style the subviews in here since they won't be initialized
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self styleViews];
}

- (void)styleViews
{
     //access my properties and style them in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following post contains detailed explanation about creating custom views using Nib:

[creating custom view using Nib](https://medium.com/@brianclouser/creating-a-custom-view-using-a-xib-in-objective-c-6041140a16ca)

After I create the customInit as mentioned in the post, I am able to get the IBOutlets allocated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Since external links may expire, leaving the answer less useful, can you add the basic steps, or a summary, from the link to your answer?